# Transition of clip path - how to change direction?

Tags: css, clip-path

I am working with clip-path, and have created a box with a cut-off corner. When hovered, it closes up and becomes a full square. What I am interesting in, is it possible to choose the direction it closes? From now it closes bottom-out, but I would like it to close top-down. Is this at all doable?

```css
.shape {
  width: 400px;
  height: 243px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.shape:before {
  content: '';
  width: 398px;
  height: 241px;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.shape,
.shape:before {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 20%, 100% 80%, 80% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 80%, 0% 20%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 20%, 100% 80%, 80% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 80%, 0% 20%);
}

.shape:hover {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 20%, 100% 80%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 80%, 0% 20%);
}

.shape:hover:before {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 20%, 100% 80%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 80%, 0% 20%);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you have complicated the polygon?

Comment: To be able to handle borders on the polygon - it seemed like the simplest solution of doing so

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 `80%`, adjust the first one not the second one.

```css
.shape {
  width: 400px;
  height: 243px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.shape:before {
  content: '';
  width: 398px;
  height: 241px;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.shape,
.shape:before {                  /* this one -----v */
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 20%, 100% 80%, 80% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.shape:hover,
.shape:hover:before{
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 20%, 100% 100%, 80% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your clip-path as follows... just swap a few % values.

```css
.shape {
  width: 400px;
  height: 153px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.shape:before {
  content: '';
  width: 398px;
  height: 151px;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.shape,
.shape:before {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 80%, 80% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}

.shape:hover {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 80% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}

.shape:hover:before {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 80% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```